# Facebook : HTTPS is required for all Redirect URIs

Tags: facebook-graph-api, https, oauth

I am trying to use facebook sdk for facebook login.

I gave http://localhost as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs but it throws the following error

> HTTPS is required for all Redirect URIs.

I used this future few days ago it worked fine. but now it throws this error

And I am not able to disable

> Enforce HTTPS

option

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you should probably be using `https` all the time anyway.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I agree with you, but I want to test it and learn how it works locally.

Comment: same issue, they changed the flow in the dashboard, how to test the app in localhost?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue with my Rails app that I usually run with http://localhost:3000.

To use https, I used [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which allows you to use https by providing a tunnel.  To do this:

1. I went to their website and downloaded their program
2. I extracted the file for the program
3. In my console, I went into the directory where ngrok was extracted to and entered 'grok http 3000' on my Windows machine, others may use './grok http 3000'
4. After entering that, ngrok provided a https address which I put into the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field in Facebook
5. Then I started my server and was able to access it using that https address instead of localhost:3000

Comment: Work well. I recommend setting up Ngrok as well.

Answer (score 1):

yep, they changed that recently :-(
For testing the login flow locally I installed a self-signed certificate 
https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

btw, I doesn't have to be trusted by the browser if you're OK with a one time security warning.

Don't use this certificate in production!